# LogBack RollingFileAppender Not Writing Log File (Though FileAppender works)

Tags: java, file, logging, logback, rollingfileappender

I'm trying to programmatically configure LogBack's `RollingFileAppender` (`ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender`) and it doesn't seem to be working. When I'm using `FileAppender`, everything seems to be working fine with exact same configuration (less policies/trigger) so I'm guessing it's not a permission issue. I tried commenting out all policy configuration and that didn't help either. Below is my sample code, with some hard-coded values. Also, there's no error at all what so ever. When I debug the LogBack source code, I didn't see anything that could have gone wrong.

Any hint is appreciative. I need to get this working without a configuration file since that's a restriction in my organization. I'm testing this out on a MacBook.

```
Logger logger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(applicationName); 
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(); 
lc.reset(); 

RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = 
    new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>(); 
fileAppender.setAppend(true); 
fileAppender.setFile("/Users/Jack/Desktop/logs/" + applicationName + ".log"); 
fileAppender.setContext(lc); 

SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rPolicy = 
    new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent>("20MB"); 
fileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(rPolicy); 
TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> tPolicy = 
    new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>(); 
tPolicy.setFileNamePattern("/archive/" + applicationName + ".%d"); 
tPolicy.setMaxHistory(180); 
tPolicy.setParent(fileAppender); 
tPolicy.setContext(lc); 

PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout(); 
pl.setPattern("%d %5p %t [%c:%L] %m%n)"); 
pl.setContext(lc); 
pl.start(); 

fileAppender.setLayout(pl); 
fileAppender.start(); 

logger.addAppender(fileAppender); 
logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG); 

logger.debug("Test message");
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. I forgot to set the RollingPolicy so the appender never started. I assumed that it throws an exception when it's not able to start so I overlooked this part.

Comment: This was working fine last week after setting the RollingPolicy and it suddenly stopped. I'm currently looking for a way to programmatically enable debug mode to see what's going on. It's definitely not permission issue since FileAppender still works. The other thread is available here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482359/programmatically-enable-logback-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key issues are as follow:

- `RollingFileAppender` must have `RollingPolicy`
- `RollingFileAppender` requires `PatternLayoutEncoder` instead of `PatternEncoder`
- `RollingPolicy` must also be started or certain properties will be null

What made this very difficult to figure out is that I couldn't figure out how to make `BasicStatusManager` print out error message. I ended up having to use the following code to print everything out.

```
for(Status status : logger.getLoggerContext().getStatusManager().getCopyOfStatusList()){
    System.out.println(status.getOrigin() + " - " + status.getMessage());
}
```

There is a separate thread going on as mentioned in the comment above on why LogBack log messages are not printing out. I also have an email thread going on with Nabble. Will post the solution in that thread as soon as I or someone can figure this out.

Comment: Really useful answer. I just want to add that before starting `RollingFileAppender`, you must first set the `RollingPolicy`'s parent to to the `RollingFileAppender` instance and then `start()` the rolling policy. It has to be in this order.